# laravel Socialite facebook login

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

I use laravel-sozialite for facebook login.
I got access token from https://developers.facebook.com
And wrote this code:

```
Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken('XXXAccessTokenXXX');
```

But instead of user infromation, I got this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given, called in /application/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php on line 126

I use :

`"laravel/socialite": "^4.2"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you are missing to give credentials of social media put that in `config/services.php`

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_FACEBOOK'),
    ]
```

And run the following commands :

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you have missed out on providing `client_id`, `redirect_url` in the `.env` file, check again.
If they exist, do a `dd(Socialite::driver($service));` and check the parameters being passed.